# Constraint return type of static method to current class type

Tags: c#

I have a class hierarchy and a static method in the base class, so subclasses have this static method too. I would love to define a static method like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>()
    where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    return new List<T>() { ... };
}
```

so I would be able to call

```
var list = ChildClass.GetList();
```

and list would be `IEnumerable<ChildClass>`. But: I don't know how to tell the compiler to infer generic type to be type of the class I call from, so this usage yields an error and I have to correct it to somehow redundant

```
var list = ChildClass.GetList<ChildClass>();
```

I could use extension methods (they have `this` argument that allows compiler to catch on), but I want do this without instantiation of `ChildClass`.

Is there a way to accomplish this without repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the compiler infer the class you call from because technically you always call from the class the method is defined in.

The compiler allowing you to use a derived class name instead is simply a convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with an ugly hack, you can make `BaseClass` itself generic, and pass the child class' type as argument to the generic parameter, like:

```
class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>, new()
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetList()
    {
        return new List<T>() { new T() }; // whatever
    }
}

class Child : BaseClass<Child>
{

}

class Child2 : BaseClass<Child2>
{

}
```

Now `Child.GetList()` returns an `IEnumerable<Child>` and `Child2.GetList()` returns an `IEnumerable<Child2>`.

Comment: Until someone creates an `EvilChild: BaseClass<Child1>`

Comment: @Servy Yeah, that's why ugly hacks are called ugly and hacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know why the compiler cannot resolve the type, read on:

Firstly static methods are bound to types not objects. So there can not be any polymorphic behaviour here. So the fact that you have a child, baseclass hierarchy is not really important here as the methods are bound to two completely different entities.

The real issue is in the type inference capabilities of the C# compiler. You have to give the compiler some information on what the type `T` is. Otherwise it cannot infer it.

You cannot give this information on the left hand side either as the C# type inference works from right to left. In other words:

```
var ints = new {};
```

Is perfectly fine. Because the type on the right is an anonymous method and ints is resolved to one. But:

```
int[] ints = new [] {};
```

Wouldn't work. The compiler complains that "no best type was found for the implicitly-typed array". In other words the compiler cannot use the information on the left hand side to figure out what the type should be on the right hand side.

In you question

```
var list = ChildClass.GetList();
```

Does not give the compiler any information on what T is ! Even if you had the type instead of var that would have not made a difference.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer! I know about right-to-left interference, but I am not sure how much it applies there. If you consider chain calls `list.Where(...).Select(...)`, then the type information actually flows to the right -- you do not have to type lambdas in last select because you know what `list` is. In the same way, there COULD be a `THIS` type-level equivalent of `this` keyword, that would be available in static methods. Of course, I understand that that would be overly complex thing to do given that the fact that static methods are "inherited" is in itself kind of surprising. :-)